# Specified font not being used in Firefox on macOS

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

I'm having this weird problem where Firefox (macOS version) is not using the font specfied in CSS for a specific piece of text, while Safari does it fine. This is the website: https://raider.io/characters/us/tichondrius/Vinomage

This is what Safari renders:

[image]

This is what Firefox renders:

[image]

I checked the inspector and it seems Safari is using "Salesforce Sans" for this region, but Firefox, **despite also showing the computed `font-family` to be "Salesforce Sans"**, is actually using "Apple Braille Outline 6 Dot" for this region:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Works fine for me in FF 86 and Mac

Comment: @TarunLalwani Hmm after a FF update the issues went away. Maybe there was a bug fix.

Comment: I am able to see the `same` rendering of  ascii art both in `Safari` in `Firefox`  Latest version too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to the latest Firefox version `86.0` or higher, that should fix the issue. This may have been a glitch in the version you were currently using